# After a MAJOR version is created, how do I retrieve previous minor versions

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, versioning, version-history

I had a Word file on a SP team site. When 500 minor versions accumulated, it would not accept further edits UNLESS a MAJOR version was started from the same file.

I did that. Now the version is 1.1. Fine. However, I need to see somethings in an old minor version numbered 450 or so...

The problem is I do not see ANY of the previous minor versions when I go to Version History of the current 1.1. There is no history.

Answer (score 1):

Minor versions are permanently deleted once you Publish a Major version.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint server, the maximum number of minor file versions is 511 and this limit cannot be exceeded.

Please go to site Recycle bin to check if you have deleted all minor versions.

------------------------------------Update---------------------------------------

If the major version has exceeded the number you set, it will be deleted automatically, meanwhile, minor versions under the major version will also be deleted.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. No, I did not delete anything other than just Publish a major version from the Advanced menu when I reached 511 minor versions. And no, it is not in the Recycled area. The new question then is: When a major version is published, does SP automatically delete previous minor versions?

Comment: Please refer to the updated answer.